# is there a way to clean a Katalon workspace

Tags: katalon-studio

I'm not sure if workspace is the right terminology but I am using Katalon and have 2 irritating issues debugging.  I suspect they are related..

1)  Old breakpoints that have been cleared are being hit quite often (I've cleared some more recently and they are properly cleared so I wondor if there is a point in time where some were not emptied out properly)

2) One test case/script that gets called by a test suite is showing a different script when being debugged.  This is very odd as it is actually running the right script in code but is sowing a different one and stopping at unrelated break points.

Is there a way to clean Katalon degug config out in some way?

Has anyone else experienced this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Katalon has a degug option that you can try: file > Clean.

You can try to read more [here](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/manage-test-project.html#clean-up-project).